# How can Javascript understand Vue file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've just started to learn Vue and I wonder, how is it made? I see in the begining of `main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
```

and the content of `App.vue` is not Javascript at all. How is it made to be understandable by Javascript?

Comment: As I know, it is called Parsing in JavaScript. With packages such as: babel, eslint, ... it can read files and parsed to correct data

Comment: Webpack uses vue-loader(https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/) to load vue files.

Comment: Javascript doesn't understand Vue. Vue gets compiled to Javascript code with a module bundler (usually Webpack or Vite).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using .vue files in a Vue application, it is necessary to use the **vue-loader** dependency. This library is a loader for webpack that allows you to create Vue components in a Single-File Components format.

[Documentation](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader):

> There are many cool features provided by vue-loader:
>
> - Allows using other webpack loaders for each part of a Vue component,
>   for example Sass for  and Pug for .
> - Allows custom
>   blocks in a .vue file that can have custom loader chains applied to
>   them.
> - Treat static assets referenced in  and  as
>   module dependencies and handle them with webpack loaders.
> - Simulate
>   scoped CSS for each component.
> - State-preserving hot-reloading during
>   development.